# Paymill: how do I view transactions for a subscription?

Tags: paymill

[Paymill](https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/): Given a subscription, what is the `curl` command to list the transactions associated with that subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you cannot list the transactions of a specific subscription, but you can list the transactions of a client by adding "?client=CLIENT_ID" to the "List transactions" endpoint. Like this:

`curl https://api.paymill.de/v2/transactions?client=client_1b6b8b4003603f1f3cbd \
  -u 319ffd1f1d10766e59350568170e8c70:`

If you run this command, you'll get 2 transactions. If you remove the "client" query string part, you'll get 3 transactions.

Note that the description for all subscription transactions starts with "Subscription#" and contains the subscription ID in it (sub_ef984bab97c253a0a372). So, you can filter the ones matching one (or all) of these conditions.

Comment: Thanks. Future payments might fail (e.g. card expires). So, every month, I'll need to do this for every client and check the status of the last transaction to know if I was paid.

Comment: Another note Juraci - I see you work at Paymill … if you didn't work there how would you know about the client `parameter`. It's not listed in the API docs. I am wondering if there are any other useful options which aren't listed!

Comment: The documentation indeed some love, but this option in particular is documented under the "List View" part of the API Reference: https://www.paymill.com/de-de/dokumentation/referenz/api-referenz/index.html#document-common-list .

Comment: In short: pretty much all first-level parameters you receive in a "GET" request can be used as a filter. In your case: the GET to "transactions" can be filtered by passing the "client" parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the extra comments - very useful!

Comment: In fact … useful enough for me to create a pull request for the ruby wrapper :) https://github.com/dkd/paymill-ruby/pull/15