# Paymill: how do I retrieve the last 10 transactions for a client?

Tags: paymill

Paymill: given I have a client with multiple subscriptions, how do I return the last 10 transactions for the client?

I know the below will give me transactions belonging to my client, but I want to return the last 10, in reverse date order.

`curl https://api.paymill.de/v2/transactions?client=client_1b6b8b4003603f1f3cbd -u my_private_paymill_key:` *

This **doesn't** seem to work but I expected it to:

`curl https://api.paymill.de/v2/transactions?client=client_1b6b8b4003603f1f3cbd&order=created_at_desc&count=10 -u my_private_paymill_key:`

---

* *I think the `client` parameter is undocumented; I found out about it from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322840/paymill-how-do-i-view-transactions-for-a-subscription).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to retrieve the last transactions for a subscription.  We're going to take this as a feature request so you can filter transactions by their description (which contains the subscription ID).

Comment: I have been able to do what I wanted. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`curl "https://api.paymill.de/v2/transactions?client=client_1b6b8b4003603f1f3cbd&order=created_at_desc&count=10" -u my_private_paymill_key:`

(needed extra quote marks around the URL!)